# Can i use two mergeMap together in RxJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, rxjs

I have been started using RxJs with redux and i have created a stream which is working. Here's my action pipe:

```js
action$.pipe(
            ofType(DELETE_CALL_HISTORY),
            withLatestFrom(state$),
            mergeMap(() =>
                fromPromise(accessService.getCallHistory()).pipe(
                    mergeMap((res: any) => of(deleteCallHistory(res))),
                    mergeMap((res: any) => of(setCallHistory(res.param))),
                    catchError((err: any) => {
                        console.error(err);
                        return of(
                            showErrorAndHideAfterDelay({
                                message: err,
                                label: 'Error',
                            }),
                        );
                    }),

                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Here i have been trying to use three actions. `getCallHistory` action is fetching the data first. `deleteCallHistory` action is deleting an item from the list. The action pipe is working till here. After this, i'm trying to set the updated list with the action`setCallHistory`. But this is not working. The setCallHistory action is getting called but when i reload the app, the deleted items are back. Should i use `mergeMap` like this twice or do need to use anything else?

Comment: Where does `getCallHistory` get the data from? is `setCallHistory` being called? It is actually _saving_ the changed data to the source?

Answer (score 0):

Note to your code:

```
  // ...
  mergeMap((res: any) => of(deleteCallHistory(res))),
  // now pipeline contains response of the deleteCallHistory
  mergeMap((res: any) => of(setCallHistory(res.param))), 
  //...
```

Don't you forget wrap the API calls with `fromPromise`?:

```
  // ...
  mergeMap((res: any) => fromPromise(deleteCallHistory(res))),
  // now pipeline contains response of the deleteCallHistory
  mergeMap((res: any) => fromPromise(setCallHistory(res.param))), 
  //...
```

To execute N API calls in sequence use [`concat`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat):

```
  import { concat } from 'rxjs';
  // ...
  mergeMap((res: any) => concat(
    of(deleteCallHistory(res))),
    of(setCallHistory(res.param))),
  ),
  //...
```

To execute N API calls in parallel use [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge):

```
  import { merge } from 'rxjs';
  // ...
  mergeMap((res: any) => merge(
    of(deleteCallHistory(res))),
    of(setCallHistory(res.param))),
  ),
  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling **mergeMap** and use **of** on the inside?

The following are very close to being equivalent:

```
mergeMap((res: any) => of(deleteCallHistory(res)))
```

```
map((res: any) => deleteCallHistory(res)))
```

They will both pass the result of **deleteCallHistory** on in the stream.  The mistake is likely there.  If **deleteCallHistory** returns an observable then that observable will never be executed since the result is an observable wrapped in an observable by **of**.

So, if **deleteCallHistory** returns a promise or observable you can just call **mergeMap** without having to wrap **deleteCallHistory** in anything:

```
mergeMap((res: any) => deleteCallHistory(res))
```

This could be an issue when calling **setCallHistory** as well.  If you don't need to pass along the result from it, you can use **tap** or **do** and if it returns an observable or promise, then don't use **of**.